# why i can't see some code while i'm debugging in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, debugging

I wanna see code inside some package while i'm debugging

[image]

I thought i can reach the code if i click the line in the Frames tab like the picture above

But i can't reach from the upper line of URL class

[image]

like this.

why is like this and how can i see the code so that i know why my app doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

it could be because the release build variant (which you can set in the Build-Variants section) has been chosen mistakenly, only debug-variant is debuggable.

Hope this can be helpful to you.

```
buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
}
debug {
    debuggable true
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
}
```

}